# How to implement <f:setPropertyActionListener> programmatically

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandlink

Basically i'm trying to set a dynamic columns for a `<p:datatable>`.

The content of one of my columns is a `p:commandLink` which used to show a dialog for text editing, i have this working like a charm in the XHTML but I need to translate it to Java for dynamic user customization and preferences.

here is what is my XHTML version:

```
<p:commandLink id="MRepShowButton" update=":form1:display" onclick="EditorDialog.show();"  title="Editer le compte rendu"> 
     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{exam}" target="#{examenListBean.selectedExamen}" />  
</p:commandLink>
```

and this is my Java version(not working):

```
CommandLink rapstatelink = (CommandLink)application.createComponent(CommandLink.COMPONENT_TYPE);
rapstatelink.setId("MRepShowButton");
rapstatelink.setUpdate(":form1:display");
rapstatelink.setOnclick("EditorDialog.show();");
rapstatelink.setTitle("Editer le rapport du patient");

ValueExpression target = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{exam}", Object.class);
ValueExpression value = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{examenListBean.selectedExamen}", Object.class);


//rapstatelink.setActionListener(new SetPropertyActionListenerHandler(**i don't know wht to do here **));
column.getChildren().add(rapstatelink);
 table.getChildren().add(column);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`UICommand#addActionListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UICommand.html#addActionListener%28javax.faces.event.ActionListener%29), not [`UICommand#setActionListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UICommand.html#setActionListener%28javax.faces.el.MethodBinding%29). The `setActionListener()` is a deprecated method from JSF 1.x which effectively does a `<p:commandLink actionListener="...">` with a `ValueBinding`.

As to creating the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` programmatically, there's unfortunately no JSF implementation independent way for that. Choose either of the following options:

1. Use the JSF implementation specific class, in case of Mojarra that's the `com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SetPropertyActionListenerImpl`:

   ```
   link.addActionListener(new SetPropertyActionListenerImpl(target, value));
   ```

   In case of MyFaces that's the `org.apache.myfaces.event.SetPropertyActionListener`:

   ```
   link.addActionListener(new SetPropertyActionListener(target, value));
   ```

   Keep in mind that using JSF implementation specific classes `com.sun.faces.*` or `org.apache.myfaces.*` in your own code is a poor practice.

   ---
2. Create a custom `ActionListener` implementation which does the job. Basically, just copypaste the class' source code from either [Mojarra](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/taglib/jsf_core/SetPropertyActionListenerImpl.java#SetPropertyActionListenerImpl) or [MyFaces](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl/2.1.12/org/apache/myfaces/event/SetPropertyActionListener.java#SetPropertyActionListener) source code into your package. As compared to 1) this has the advantage that your web application does not break when deployed to a Java EE container which ships with the other JSF implementation bundled.

   ---
3. Make use of EL 2.2 feature of the ability to pass method arguments in EL expressions. Then you can just do the job in `action` or `actionListener` attribute:

   ```
   link.setActionExpression(ef.createMethodExpression(elc, 
      "#{examenListBean.setSelectedExamen(exam)}", Void.class, Exam.class));
   ```

   *(the `Exam.class` should represent the type of `#{exam}`)*

   This does effectively the same as

   ```
   <p:commandLink ... action="#{examenListBean.setSelectedExamen(exam)}" />
   ```

   Or if you really need to set an action listener:

   ```
   link.addActionListener(new MethodExpressionActionListener(ef.createMethodExpression(elc, 
      "#{examenListBean.setSelectedExamen(exam)}", Void.class, Exam.class)));
   ```

   This does effectively the same as

   ```
   <p:commandLink ... actionListener="#{examenListBean.setSelectedExamen(exam)}" />
   ```

Comment: always astonished with your full spec answers, thank you very much.

Comment: You can the Mojarra implementation from https://github.com/javaee/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/taglib/jsf_core/SetPropertyActionListenerImpl.java